# Are these alternatives to Invoke-Expression really any safer? And why?

Tags: powershell

I'm not understanding if `Invoke-Expression` is internally flawed, making it more dangerous.  Or is the problem that it incorporates text to code, code to execution, and maybe execution in the local scope, all in a single command.

What I'm wanting to do is create a class in C# with a `public event EventHandler MyEvent;` event via `Add-Type`, and then inherit from that class in PowerShell by writing the PowerShell in a string `@'class psMessages: csMessages{<code for clas>}'@`, converting the string into a script block, and then executing it.

I found these methods for creating the script block will work:

```
$ScriptBlock = ([System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($psMessages, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)).GetScriptBlock()
# or
$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($psMessages)
```

And either of these commands will execute the the script block in the current scope:

```
. $ScriptBlock
# or
Invoke-Command -NoNewScope $ScriptBlock
```

**Additional info:** These commands fail, I believe because they execute the script block in a new scope - please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
& $ScriptBlock
# or
$ScriptBlock.Invoke()
# or
Invoke-Command $ScriptBlock
```

So, are any of these methods safer to use than `Invoke-Expression`? Or are they all just as dangerous?  And, if any are safer, why?

Comment: The advantage Scriptblock has over `Invoke-Expression` comes from it's `CheckRestrictedLanguage` method (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70486907/15339544) in addition to, once instantiated you can automatically inspect the AST prior to invoking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **What makes any command dangerous is the blind execution of source code from an *unknown / untrusted* source**.

  - As such, the execution *mechanism* is incidental to the problem.
- Conversely, this means that **if you *full control* or *implicitly trust* a given piece of source code, use of [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) - which is [generally to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) - *is* acceptable**.

  - Note that the code executed by `Invoke-Expression` invariably runs in the *current* scope; you could wrap the input string in `& { ... }` in order to execute it in a *child* scope.
- As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, **[`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) enables a *middle ground***:

  - As demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70486907/45375) of his, **it is possible to *constrain* what may be executed** in terms of permissible commands, read access to specific variables, and whether read access to environment variables is allowed.
  - Additionally, a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) instance returned by `[scriptblock]::Create()` allows potentially reusable invocation on demand, with the choice to either execute it in the *current* scope, with `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), or a *child* scope, with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

---

As for the **commands listed under "Additional info:"**

- They should *not* fail; they should  all execute the script block in a *child* scope.
- However:

  - Using the `.Invoke()` method on script blocks should be avoided, because it changes the semantics of the call in several respects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220711/45375).
  - Similarly, there is no good reason to use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) for (local) invocation of script blocks - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980641/45375).