# Retrieve the value "They can swim" through another varialbe?

Tags: powershell

## Input:

I want to print variable `$VarX` value by referencing its name through another variable, `$VarA`:

---

## Code:

```
$VarX = "They can swim"
$VarA = '$VarX'
"What do dogs do? $($VarA)"
```

I also tried this:

```
$VarX = "They can swim"
$VarA = '$VarX'
"What do dogs do? `$($VarA)"
```

---

## Desired Output:

```
What do dogs do? They can swim
```

---

Edit1: More expalanation as requested

I am writing a PowerShell script that will let me write then execute a simple AutoHotkey script at the terminal. So I can test very simple lines of code in AutoHotkey. This is something I am constantly finding myself doing:

- Need to test AHK code
- Create a `.ahk` file in some random path
- `#include <json>`
- `#include...`
- Test done
- Forget to delete file

I want to instead do this at the terminal:

```
Interactive-AHK 'MsgBox, % "The current version is " A_AhkVersion' 

Interactive-AHK "MsgBox, % "The current version is " A_AhkVersion" -NoHeaderFooter

"@
MsgBox, % "The current version is " A_AhkVersion
"@ | Interactive-AHK AdvancedHeader, AdvancedExit
```

The command is stored in a `.psm1` file, there are also variables stored in this same file, which I need to be able to reference in the function but hide from the terminal:

```
Function Build-AutHotkeyScript{
    param(
        [parameter(Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Code,
        [parameter(Position = 2)]
        [ArgumentCompletions("SingleNoenvJson", "AdvancedHeader", "BasicExit", "AdvancedExit")]
        [Array]$HeaderFooter = "SingleNoenvJson", "BasicExit"     #This may make no sense but its how I like to work
        [switch]$NoHeaderFooter
    )
    $Source = "C:\Users\..\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\AutoHotkey\Resources\InteractiveAHK.ahk"  #The Path which to set the content to
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $Source -Value "$($NoHeaderFooter -eq $True ? $null : $HeaderFooter[0]), $Code, $($NoHeaderFooter -eq $True ? $null : $HeaderFooter[1])" # If "NoHeaderFooter Switch is used dont preappend or append anything to the $Code string"
    . $source       # Run the file
}

# ---- Headers ----
    $SingleNoenvJson = @"
    #singleinstance, force
    #NoEnv
    #Include <Json>
    "@
    $AdvancedHeader = @"
    #singleinstance, force
    #Include <XML>
    #Include <SomeSuperCoolLib>
    #Include <HackingTheSystem>
    [Some more line]
    "@

    [More Headers coming soon ]

# ---- Footers ----
    $BasicExit = @"
    ExitApp
    [Some more lines coming soon]
    [Some more lines coming soon]
    "@

    $AdvancedExit = @"
    ExitApp
    [Some more lines coming soon]
    [Some more lines coming soon]
    "@

    [More Footers coming soon ]
```

With an invocation of `Interactive-AHK 'MsgBox, % "The current version is " A_AhkVersion'` , the `InteractiveAHK.ahk` file should look like:

```
#singleinstance, force
#NoEnv
#Include <Json>

MsgBox, % "The current version is " A_AhkVersion

ExitApp
[Some more lines coming soon]
[Some more lines coming soon]
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Can you give a concrete example? I'm guessing you're trying to build something dynamic, where the contents of the variable determines behavior. If that's the case, there are *many* better ways of accomplishing your objective. But in order to make a recommendation, we need to understand the objective.

Comment: @DanielMann, Hello I edited my post and added more context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable?view=powershell-7.3) if trimming the `$` from that string, otherwise you can use [`ExpandString` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.expandstring?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0):

```
$VarX = 'They can swim'
$VarA = '$VarX'
"What do dogs do? $(Get-Variable $VarA.Trim('$') -ValueOnly)"
"What do dogs do? $($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($VarA))"
```

Creating a scriptblock from `$VarA` and invoking or using `Invoke-Expression` would also be a possibility:

```
"What do dogs do? $([scriptblock]::Create($VarA).InvokeReturnAsIs())"
```

**Do note this would allow for arbitrary code execution and you should be very careful if this comes from user input. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70486907/15339544) for some ways you could prevent this.**

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the varied examples and for the heads up warnig too.